# Full Calendar 'SlotDuration' slot shows empty slot at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am currently working on full calendar plugin (3.9.0) and I try to show an hour in each time slot , however it shows an empty space at the bottom .I am sharing my code pen which has the issue
`enter code here` JsFiddle: https://codepen.io/kamakoti/pen/yLXRJex .

Comment: Please include all relevant code _here_ in your question, not just in an external site. Questions which don't so this can be marked as off topic and deleted - see the [help/on-topic] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting

```
height: 'auto'
```